# Search Engine showing certain pages

Tags: wordpress, search, seo, sitemap, google-search

I have a question regarding search engines. I'm currently running a wordpress website but I have 84 standalone pages that are not linked to by a menu.

The goal was to have a landing page for certain big cities in my country, so when sombody google's webdesign in X city, they would see a landing page for that city.

Now the problem is, these pages are not on any search engine. How can I fix this? Or wat causes this issue?

I've already submitted my sitemap to both Google & Bing and all the pages are indexed except for the standalone pages.

Answer (score -1):

You can submit your landing page in Google place. So, When somebody will google certain cities for your similer kind of business they will see your webpage as pinned on location! Like Google Maps pin!

For that off you have to submit your business details, including name, address, and category your business falls under. You also must let Google know if you deliver goods or services to customers from your business location.

Once you complete your information, you’ll be told you have to verify your information, via a postcard. You can choose to verify later, which will take you to your Google Places page. But any changes you make on that page won’t appear until you verify your business, so it’s worth your while to just verify now. A postcard will be sent to the address you listed in roughly 1 – 2 weeks, with a PIN that you have to provide to Google.